# What does " int? get priority => 1;" do?

Tags: flutter, syntax, arrow-functions, flutter-getx

I was reading a flutter code as below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:test_get_app/user_controller.dart';

class AuthMiddleware extends GetMiddleware {
  final authService = UserController.findOrInitialize; // Here is error, this line can't find UserController
  @override
  int? get priority => 1;
  bool isAuthenticated = false;

  @override
  RouteSettings? redirect(String? route) {
    isAuthenticated = true;
    if (isAuthenticated == false) {
      return const RouteSettings(name: '/login');
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

When I reached to the following line, I couldn't understand it's syntax and how does it work?

```
  int? get priority => 1;
```

Comment: Read here https://pub.dev/packages/get#priority

Comment: `int?` means `priority` getter has privilege to return null, while you are already returning non-null value 1, you can remove `?` .

Comment: @YeasinSheikh: My problem is this part `priority => 1;`

Comment: ok, then I think it depends on `get` package, you can follow above link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `int?` Means it is an int but the int can be null
- `=> 1` Means `() {return 1;}`

Answer (score 1):

This is a so-called getter. Getters can be used to provide read access to class properties.

They can also return values directly, like in your case.

They are accessed like properties of the class they are declared in:

```dart
final middleWare = AuthMiddleware();
final priority = middleWare.priority;
```

In your case the getter probably must or can be implemented (see the `@override` annotation), since all implementations of a middleware must declare their priority, I guess. Since the declared type is `int?` it may also return `null` instead of an integer.

Getters can be declared using an expression. Like in your case. Using a block body does also work:

```dart
int? get priority {
  return 1;
}
```